# How to generate html with coverage data?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I built bitcoin as:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --without-gui --enable-lcov
make -j4
./src/test/test_bitcoin
```

I see bunch of *.gcno files. How do I generate html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured that out.

After you run tests, you will see a bunch of *.gcno files. Then, do:

```
# better to work in a separate dir
mkdir cov && cd cov
lcov -c -d ../src -o cov.info
genhtml cov.info
```

And open `index.html` `cov` dir.